# How to use cmis for multiple content repositories?

Tags: search, integration, cmis

I want to use CMIS in case where there are multiple repositories (same vendor or different vendors) and CMIS is used to integrate all these repositories onto a common platform.

E.g. CMIS is used to fetch content from all repositories simultaneously say in search scenario.

Any idea?

Regards.

Comment: One approach i am thinking is to create a platform which receives a request and divide into multiple requests per cms repository & get results back. But challenge here is caching of content & handling of such requests.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS provides a component that is called the CMIS Bridge. It acts a CMIS server for clients and routes the CMIS requests to back-end systems. You can put your own business logic on the bridge that transforms, filters, enriches, and federates data on the way.
But, at this point, the CMIS Bridge is rather basic and not well documented. Although, there is already a commercial product using this component.

Comment: Thanks Florian. Are you talking about OpenCMIS Server Framework @ http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/dev-server.html. Does it support multiple repositories as back end such as alfresco as one repo & say documentum as another repo? Indded, documentation is very weak here.

Comment: The OpenCMIS Server Framework is one part of the bridge. Go to the download page and get the CMIS Bridge package. The default implementation only provides a one-to-one mapping. You would have to plug in your own code that does the federation. (It has been done ...)

Comment: I have downloaded it & its a war of about 5 MB. Still struggling on how to use it and make a start. There is no documentation i can see on apache opnecmis site.Can you help?

Comment: 3 years later.. i've just come across identical requirement in my project. September 2016 release of version 1.0.0 occurred, so I assume that project is still alive. Do you possess any documentation, github project's link, you can share? I would be very grateful for any information, especially concerning data federation? Is this really achiveable with OpenCmis Bridge?

Comment: Get the OpenCMIS Bridge code from [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/chemistry/opencmis/trunk/chemistry-opencmis-bridge/chemistry-opencmis-bridge/) or [here](https://github.com/apache/chemistry-opencmis/tree/trunk/chemistry-opencmis-bridge/chemistry-opencmis-bridge). Change all the forwarding.* properties in
 /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/repository.properties. Compile and deploy it and you have a first simple bridge running.

Comment: The OpenCMIS Bridge code is rather a template than a library. Eventually, you must decide how to manage/cache sessions to the backend systems (two implementations are included, HTTP sessions and LRU cache). And depending on your use-case you may want to extend or replace the FilterCmisService class. The default code only forwards requests to the backend repository. This is only of limited use, but there is no generic solution. You must tailor it to your requirements.